# Manually dispatching actions and querying state in RTKQ

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have built an API in my React using `createApi()`, but now later in development further requirements have arisen and I am not able to use the API in a straightforward way.

I am building a tree-like component, called a `Selector`, where the children of each node are potentially fetched on demand. The data model for this `Selector` looks like this:

```
export type SelectorDataFn = (parent?: SelectorItem) => SelectorItem[];

export type SelectorData = SelectorDataFn | SelectorItem[];

export interface SelectorItem {
  id: ItemId;
  entityType: EntityType;
  description: string;
  children?: SelectorData;
}
```

where (it now transpires) the `SelectorDataFn` on this first attempt pass would be a selector. This has introduced the consideration of some very smelly patterns, and some impossible ones too: having a `useSelector()` hook somewhere other than at the top level scope of the component.

The props for my `Selector` look like this:

```
interface Props {
  rootItems: SelectorData;
  icon: IconDefinition;
  title: string;
  onCancel?: () => void;
}

export const Selector = ({ rootItems, icon, title, onCancel }: Props) => {
    // ...
}
```

I had considered creating a state or perhaps a memo of these selectors, creating them on demand and returning them from my `SelectorItem.children`, which seemed like a pitiful way to shoehorn my logic into RTKQ. I could then unwrap the selector in my `SelectorColumn` (think macOS Finder or Windows Explorer) using `useSelector()`, but I would have to pass in a dummy selector in the case that the `SelectorItem` had no children that simply retuned no data.

So my next thought was to address the store directly using `connect()`. But having a read around suggests that this is at best a pretty bad idea: dispatching actions manually and writing a `mapStateToProps` method.

Could anyone suggest an architecture that might work for this? ChatGPT let me down too

Comment: I have asked ChatGPT, and it gave me some interesting suggestions, that aside, why don't use something like `react-query` or `swr` that allow you to fetch data on demand and cache it if that's what you originally wanted?

Comment: Honestly never heard of those two libraries. `react-query` looks interesting. It's just that we're already pretty involved with redux, although I am pressing to move to GraphQL. I'm going to have a read through those docs, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Although looking at it, it still uses hooks, which still makes things tricky.